# How to override specific row classes in a view preprocess function

Tags: views, theming

Have tried the following but it does not work

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$vars){
  $view = $vars['view'];
  if($view->name == "videos" && $view->current_display == "block_2"){
    $vars["rows"][0]["attributes"]["class"] = array_merge($vars["rows"][0]["attributes"]["class"],['testclass']);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Clive well thanks for the patience I am still learning the proper way of drupal.statckexchange.com questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Example:

[image]

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $view_name = $view->id();

  if ($view_name = 'frontpage') {
    $rows = $variables['rows'];
    foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
      if( in_array($id,[0]) ) { //first row only
        $attributes = $variables['rows'][$id]['attributes'];
        $attributes->removeClass('lol')->addClass('haha'); // changes "lol" to "haha"
        break;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: you beat me to answering it ... as I was getting rid of the other problem I finally got my answer to this as you describe above ... thanks

Comment: removeClass does not actually work ... does it work for you ?

Comment: @GiorgosK works for me, which class are you trying to remove? A row class that comes by default with Drupal or a class added via the Views UI (like in my answer).

Comment: I believe it has to do with the fact that I have many classes `class1 class2 class3` and they are passed as one class you are just passing 1 class `lol`  ... but its minor ... I will work around it ... thanks

Comment: maybe try `$attributes->removeClass('class1 class2 class3')->addClass('class1 haha class3')`

Comment: yes sure that is what I meant ... or only include the classes that are common and then only put if/else statement for additional classes ... thanks